# Simple error including Javascript files into a test app using basic MEAN example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, pug

I'm taking a course (on MEAN) and it starts by trying to get something running end-to-end.  The point now is to add in the Javascript necessary to make Angular work.   I'm having some kind of simple problem including the scripts.

The error I'm getting is (firebug), which appears to complain about the entire index.html file, is:

[image]

The Jade code is short.  It is an index.jade file which extends a layout.jade file which includes in all the js files:

extends ../includes/layout

```
block main-content
  section.content
    div(ng-view)
    h2 some regular text 5
```

This produces the following index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/toastr/toastr.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/app.js"></script>
    <section class="content">
      <div ng-view></div>
      <h2>some regular text 5</h2>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

================ UPDATE ========

It appears Node is substituting the index.html file for the assets.  The project directory structure is:

[image]

The server.js file which node runs is:

```
var express = require('express');
var stylus = require('stylus');

// set env variable to determine if in production or development mode; this contains environment if set my MODE
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

// create express application
var app = express();

function compile(str, path) {
    return sytle(str).set('filename', path);
}

// configure express
//app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(stylus.middleware({
    src: __dirname + '/public',
    compile: compile
}));

console.log("dirname:" + __dirname);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.get('/partials/:partialPath', function(req, res) {
   res.render('partials/' + req.params.partialPath);
});

app.use(express.logger('dev')); //- logger no longer bundled with Express
app.use(express.bodyParser());


// add routes:
// We won't tell the server specifically what routes to handle.  We'll have the client-side be
// responsible to server up and 404 notices.   Client-side will have to specify all routes.
// Other solution is to coordinate your routes, so that every client route is also listed on the server.
// Far more customary to have a server side have a catch all that lists up a 404 page.

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
})

var port = 3030;

app.listen(port);
console.log("listening on port: " + port + " ...");
```

Comment: It appears when I click on the script error in Firebug, instead of bringing up the jquery.js file, it brings up the index.html file.  It's like the index.html file is getting substituted in for the jquery.js, etc.  But the file is fine on my file system -- running from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a path issue as the page is not able to access your assets directory. Make sure your public folder is set right in your node server code. It should be along the lines of `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public_folder_name')));`. Looking at your folder structure, your server.js is nested in server folder and not at the same level as your public folder. Try `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));`

Comment: Thanks, I've got: app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  BUT the course showing example also does this:  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');   
})   // IS THIS THE PROBLEM?

Comment: `app.get('*', function(req, res) { res.render('index'); })` should come after `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` is that how your current code is structured?

Comment: yes, it comes after.  First the express.static is set, then the app.get.

Comment: Ok. If you are using bower to fetch your assets, can you crosscheck if the fetched files are placed in the vendor directive? I believe the default is bower_components folder

Comment: I'm going to add a picture of the directory structure to the question.  I'm also going to add the server.js file which Node runs.